# Ghostscript not prining accented characters correctly

Tags: linux, unicode, ghostscript

I have a Bash script that writes a text watermark to PDF files. It does this by generating an overlay PDF with Ghostscript and then using PDFtk to stamp the overlay onto the original.

All this works perfectly, except that Ghostscript is not writing accented characters correctly. If my input text is, for example, "Français", the output on the PDF will be "Franˆ§ais".

My Ghostscript command line is:

```
/usr/local/bin/gs -q -o "${TEMPFILE}" \
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPAPERSIZE=letter \
-c "60 23 moveto 0.32 0.23 0.22 setrgbcolor /Helvetica-Oblique findfont 9 scalefont setfont (${WATERMARK}) show"
```

The `$WATERMARK` variable contains a single line of text to be written. The problem occurs both when running the Bash script that contains this line and also when I run just this command directly.

I'm seeing this problem using Ghostscript 9.06 on Mac OS X (installed via Homebrew) and 9.05 on Ubuntu 12.04 (installed from the Ubuntu package repository). The Bash script and gs command line were both written by someone else; I have no experience using Ghostscript myself.

Changing the font has no effect on the problem and I've been unable to google anything useful related to this. What are we doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't encoded the font correctly (or indeed at all).

You are assuming that the character code which represents the glyph named ccedilla is the same in the font as it is on your computer system. For Latin fonts, and the ASCII characters up to 127 this is usually true, for characters beyond that it usually isn't and for non-Latin languages (eg Russian, Arabic, CJKV languages, etc) it isn't true at all.

Encoding fonts isn't hard, but it is rather lengthy to go into here, so instead let me recommend the excellent series of articles written by John Deubert of Acumen Training, you can find them here:

http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html

For your purposes I suggest the November and December 2001 articles.

Comment: This looks helpful, thanks. I'll read over these by tomorrow and update this post with my findings. Thanks!

Comment: I finally had a chance to read over these Acumen Journal articles. I don't have a working solution yet but at least now I understand what I need. Thanks again.